# ReactJS: When props is not an array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Newbie** question:  I'm learning ReactJS+Typescript.

I have a simple interface describing an array of data:

```
interface IProfile {
  name: string;
  avatar_url: string;
  company: string;
}

const testData: IProfile[] = [
 { name: "Dan Abramov", avatar_url: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4", company: "@facebook" },
 { name: "Sophie Alpert", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6820?v=4", company: "Humu" },
];
```

I have a simple call to an App function where I pass the array spread:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App {...testData} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

In the App the `props is not an array though`???:

```
class App extends React.Component<IProfile[]>  {

 constructor(props:IProfile[]) {
    super(props);
    console.log("props is array " + Array.isArray(props));  //false
 }

 public render() {
    return (<div> </div>);
 }

};
```

When I look at the props in the React Dev Tools in Chrome, it looks like an array though:

[image]

Comment: `Props` is an Object, `props.testData` is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`props` isn't an `array` is an `object`. Take a look at this piece of code from `ReactElement.js` from [React's source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3497ccc14929f6d69d8d48ef41d0b34d1751ce9d/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L158-L161)

> ```
> if (Object.freeze) {
>     Object.freeze(element.props);
>     Object.freeze(element);
> } //just showing that props is in fact an object
> ```

You're spreading an array inside an `object`. If you pass it like

```
<App storeData={storeData} />
```

Inside app `isArray` evaluates to `true` now

```
Array.isArray(props.storeData) //true
```

Your current data structure looks like this

```js
    const data = [
     { name: "Dan Abramov", avatar_url: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4", company: "@facebook" },
     { name: "Sophie Alpert", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6820?v=4", company: "Humu" },
    ]

    const props = {...data}

    console.log(props)
```

Just an object with "number like" indexes (it's actually a string `"0"`). So when visualizing from `react-dev-tools` it looks like an array but they are actually `properties` of an `object`

```
{
   "0" : 'foo',
   "1" : 'bar'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an array because you're spreading it. Spreading an array or an object removes it from the "container" and only puts in the values.